# How do I refer to grouped rows in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like the value in the cell immediately above cells in grouped rows below to reflect the max of the values in those grouped cells. Is there a way to refer to the adjacent grouped rows in this way in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following script.
Position the cursor *in any cell* in the row group (for example, B2 to B10) OR in the parent row of the group (B1).

```
function wa16385901() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")

  // get the current row and column
  var cell = sheet.getCurrentCell()
  var cellRow = cell.getRow()
  var cellCol = cell.getColumn()

  // set variables for the subroutine
  var lookAtRow = cellRow
  var lookatColumn = cellCol
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: LookatRow = "+lookAtRow+" LookatColumn = "+lookatColumn)
  
  // run the subroutine
  // hat tip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53855165/1330560
  var groupRows = findGroupRows(sheet,lookAtRow);

  if (groupRows != 0) {

    // breakdown the range
    var rangebreak = groupRows.indexOf(':')
    var firstrow = groupRows.substring(0, rangebreak)
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: firstrow in group = "+firstrow)
    var lastrow = groupRows.substring(+rangebreak+1,groupRows.length)
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: lastrow in group = "+lastrow)
    
    
    
    // define the range where the formula is to be created
    var targetCell = sheet.getRange(+firstrow-1,lookatColumn)
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the formula is inserted in "+sheet.getRange(+firstrow-1,lookatColumn).getA1Notation())
   
    // define the formula and the row range for the formula
    var formulaRange = sheet.getRange(firstrow,cellCol,lastrow-firstrow+1)
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the formula range = "+formulaRange.getA1Notation())
    let maxFormula = "=MAX(" + formulaRange.getA1Notation() + ")"; // define formula

    // set the formula
    targetCell.setFormula(maxFormula)


  } else {
    // Logger.log('DEBUG: no topic exists for row ' + lookAtRow);
  }
}

function findGroupRows(sheet, thisRow) {
  //--- if the given row is a part of a Group, then it will return the
  //    rowIndex (the row with the control) of the group, otherwise it
  //    returns 0
  
  try {
    
    // get the row group
    var rowGroup = sheet.getRowGroup(thisRow, 1)
    var groupRange = rowGroup.getRange().getA1Notation()
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: groupRange = "+groupRange)
    return groupRange;
    
  } catch (e) {
    //--- this row is not part of a group
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: this row is not part of a group")
    return 0;
  }
}
```

---

**References**

[getRowGroup](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrowgrouprowindex,-groupdepth)

[getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/group#getrange)

---

**BEFORE**

[image: before]

**AFTER**

[image: after]